# Playing a youtube video in WinJS application

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8.1, winjs

I'm getting following error while trying to play youtube link in my WinJS app.

`Can’t load <https://www.youtube.com/player_api>. An app can’t load remote web content in the local context.`

What might be the best way to play youtube videos in WinJS app?